# How To Get Clear Image From FaceBook

Tags: android, android-facebook

I used graph API Json Response of Facebook Wall Post Images and display in my APP i successfully got it. But the wall images look very Blur how to resolve? i used this code for get wall picture

```
URL url=new URL(hashMap.get("picture_url"));
bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_FullImage)).setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook Graph API as well as the FQL data set always returns the Picture URL of a thumbnail. If you look at the URL it returns, it will have one of these ending (right before the image extension .jpg, .png, etc) **_t.**, **_a.**. For example, if the URL is to a JPG file, it could have an ending **_t.jpg**

The idea is to *swap* the ending and choose a normal size for the image that is returned. To do this, use the code below that will replace the endings with the one for normal sized images (that should have the **_n.**)

By the way, I don't think the tag you are looking for is **picture_url**. It should be just **picture**. But regardless, get the source URL as shown below, replace the endings and then pass it to the this line in your code:

```
// THIS SHOULD BE AFTER THE if....else code block
bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

CODE TO REPLACE THE VARIOUS THUMBNAIL IMAGES: *By the way, this is production code and works perfect.*

```
String PICTURE_URL;
String getPicture = JOFeeds.getString("picture");

if (getPicture.contains("_t.")) {
    PICTURE_URL = getPicture.replaceAll("_t.", "_n.");
} else if (getPicture.contains("_a.")) {
    PICTURE_URL = getPicture.replaceAll("_a.", "_n.");
} else if (getPicture.contains("_s.")) {
    PICTURE_URL = getPicture.replaceAll("_s.", "_n.");
} else if (getPicture.contains("_q.")) {
    PICTURE_URL = getPicture.replaceAll("_q.", "_n.");
}
```

*Note: However, in some cases, like a Video preview or a Link preview, it will not always have a bigger image available. Nothing much you can do about it nor can Facebook I suspect. These typically come from posts that are shared by users from other websites.*